# I have required values in the field and need to copy value from value,value1,value2,value3,value4 field to course object using setState in react

Tags: reactjs

```
class RegistrationPage extends Component {
  state={
    value:'',
    value1:'',
    value2:'',
    value3:'',
    value4:'',
    course:{
      watchHref:'',title:'',authorId:'',category:'',length:''
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function to copy your value to course object in state,

```
copyVal(){
  let course = {...this.state.course};
  course.watchHref = this.state.value1;
  course.title = this.state.value2;
  course.authorId = this.state.value3;
  course.category = this.state.value3;
  course.length = this.state.value4;
   this.setState({course:course});
}
```

Comment: debugger showed values are updating to course but unfortunately,i tried to log the output by using console.log(this.state.course);I could see empty values

Comment: SetState is asynchronous, so if you want to log, you can do it in its call back function,ie, `this.setState({course:course},()=>{console.log(this.state.course)});`. And please accept the answer if the above statements worked for you.

Comment: unable to see log this time

Comment: Ok, try `this.setState({course:course},()=>{console.log(this.state)});`

Comment: By the way, values are not updating to course object present in state instead,it is just updating in this.setState({course:course}) and i wont see values are updating in state

Comment: You wanted to copy values, in Value 1,2,3,4 to course object using setState, right? Do you mean a course object which is not in state?

Comment: I am not able to understand your current problem

Comment: am trying to save the value to store before that need to update the values in state,so that i can send object to store

Comment: hope you understood the problem

Comment: line # 68 is not done as I have given in the answer and as I mentioned in my previous comment, pls add the console.log along with the setState, `this.setState({course:course},()=>{console.log(this.state)});`

Comment: {value: "chida", value1: "mmmm", value2: "888", value3: "999", value4: "111@gmail.com", …}
LNameError
:
""
course
:
authorId
:
""
category
:
""
length
:
""
title
:
""
watchHref
:
""
__proto__
:
Object
eMailError
:
""
fNameError
:
""
mNumError
:
""
registrationData
:
"Welcome To Registration Form"
sapIdError
:
""
value
:
"chida"
value1
:
"mmmm"
value2
:
"888"
value3
:
"999"
value4
:
"111@gmail.com"

Comment: I haved added and removed,since console.log is not printing

Comment: Logging as a next statement to a setstate will never show you a correct log.

Comment: Did you change the line #  68 as `let course = {...this.state.course};` ??